# MySQL FULL JOIN one table, and LEFT JOIN another in the same query?

Tags: php, mysql, join

i have three tables i would like to link in this one query.

The script is an attendance register, so it records an attendance mark for each meeting, per user.

The three tables used:

"team":

```
id | fullname | position         | class | hidden
1  | Team     | --               | black | 1
2  | Dan S    | Team Manager     | green | 0
3  | Harry P  | Graphic Engineer | blue  | 0
```

"register":

```
id | mid | uid | mark
1  | 1   | 2   | /
2  | 1   | 3   | I
3  | 2   | 1   | /
4  | 2   | 3   | /
```

"meetings":

```
id | maintask            | starttime  | endtime
1  | Organise Year Ahead | 1330007400 | 1330012800
2  | Gather Ideas        | 1330612200 | 1330617600
3  | TODO                | 1331217000 | 1331222400
```

There is a sample of the data. What i want to do is:

Select all the results from the register, group them by the user, and order them by the meeting start time. But, if there is not a mark in the register table, i want it to display "-" (can be done via php if needed) So an expected result like so:

```
fullname | mark | mid
Dan S    | /    | 1
Dan S    | /    | 2
Dan S    | -    | 3
Harry P  | I    | 1
Harry P  | /    | 2
Harry P  | -    | 3
```

My SQL Query is this at the moment:

> SELECT u.`fullname`,u.`id`,r.`mark`,r.`mid` FROM `team` u FULL JOIN `register` r ON r.`uid`=u.`id` LEFT JOIN `meetings` m ON
>   r.`mid`=m.`id` GROUP BY u.`id` ORDER BY m.`starttime` ASC

And i get an error back from MySQL:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FULL JOIN `register` r ON r.`uid`=u.`id` LEFT JOIN `meetings` m
>   ON r.`mid`=m.`id' at line 1

But, i cant see an issue with it :S

Please could someone help out, point me in the right direction or give me a possible solution to this. Much Appreciated

Dan

Answer:
Query that worked:

```
   SELECT     
       u.fullname,    u.id as uid,    
       if(r.uid = u.id, r.mark, '-') as mark,    
       if(r.uid = u.id, r.mid, '-') as mid,    
       r.mid,    m.starttime 
   FROM     
       team u 
         CROSS JOIN     
       register r ON u.id = r.uid
         LEFT OUTER JOIN     
       meetings m ON r.mid = m.id  
   WHERE    
       u.hidden = 0 
   GROUP BY     
       u.id, r.mid 
   ORDER BY     
       m.starttime, u.id ASC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Full outer join` is not supported by MySQL. At least to version 5.6, you can check [MySQL Join doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html). A `cross join` may be a workaround:

**EDITED**

```
SELECT 
   UxM.fullname,
   r.mark,
   UxM.mid,
   UxM.starttime
FROM 
   ( select u.id as uid, m.id as mid, u.fullname, m.starttime
     from
     team  u
      CROSS JOIN   
     meetings ) UxM
   left join
   register r
      on UxM.uid = r.uid and UxM.mid = r.mid
ORDER BY 
   UxM.starttime ASC
```

Let me know if this solve your issue.

---

A simplification:

```
SELECT     
    u.fullname,
    u.id AS uid,    
    COALESCE(r.mark, '-') AS mark,    
    COALESCE(r.mid, '-') AS mid,    
    m.id,
    m.starttime 
FROM     
    team u 
      CROSS JOIN     
    meetings m 
      LEFT JOIN     
    register r
        ON   r.mid = m.id  
        AND  r.id = u.uid
WHERE    
    u.hidden = 0 
GROUP BY     
    m.id, u.id 
ORDER BY     
    m.starttime, u.id
```

Comment: Ive used it in MySQL before o.O I'm sure i have
-- Maybe not, might have got confused with LEFT OUTER JOIN or something. What can i use instead of full outer join that will do the same thing?

Comment: Google for `simulate full outer join mysql` for some solutions for `FULL OUTER JOIN` which indeed does not exist in mysql.

Comment: Thank you very much, CROSS JOIN Worked perfectly :) (For some reason i cannot mark as accepted answer o.O)

Comment: Ahh, it only seems to select data where m.id = 1 :S Theres definatly an entry in the register table that uses m.id = 2 :S

Comment: @DanSpiteri, I think the right solution is cross join between team and meeting, I will rewrite the query. wait.

Comment: What i was i just replaced the FULL JOIN with CROSS JOIN, didnt notice the extra query you put up, i copied and pasted that in and it worked :P Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @DanSpiteri, I hope you have achieve a solution. I have post a last approach, test it if you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i edited your last query slightly (ill post it below the question) and it works great :) It doesnt replace the "-" though, but thats no problem, i can do that in PHP afterwards ;)